# Using %like% and JOIN together in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, join, search, sql-like

I have three tables: 'users', 'products', and 'product_types'.  The 'users' table stores all usual data about my site users (including an `id` column); the 'products' table lists the `product_id` of the product, the `user_id` of the user who added it, and the `product_type`; the 'product_types' table has an `id` column (which corresponds with the `product_type` int value in the 'products' table), and a varchar `name` column.

I want to perform a `%like%` search in the 'users' table so that when a user searches for product types, it shows all users who have products that match the searched product type.  Here's what I'm currently using in my CodeIgniter model:

```
$string = urldecode($string);
$this->db->select('users.*');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->like('users.company_name',$string,'both');
$this->db->or_like('users.address_1',$string,'both');
$this->db->or_like('users.city',$string,'both');
$this->db->or_like('users.contact',$string,'both');
$this->db->or_like('product_types.name',$string,'both');
$this->db->join('products','users.id = products.client_id');
$this->db->join('product_types','products.product_type = product_types.id');
$this->db->distinct();
$users = $this->db->get();
foreach($users->result() as $user){
   // search result
}
```

I then feed this into a foreach statement... But it's only showing the first row most of the time - other times it comes back with no results.  Can anybody tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Try printing `$this->db->last_query();` which shows the SQL query that was run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont understand why you are making multiple queries, it can be accomplished only in one query

```
    SELECT a.*,b.*,C.* FROM users a LEFT JOIN products b ON b.user_id = a.id LEFT JOIN product_types c ON b.product_type = c.id WHERE a.company_name LIKE '%$string%' OR a.address_1 LIKE '%$string%' OR a.city LIKE '%$string%' a.contact LIKE '%$string%' b.name LIKE '%$string%'
```

this will give you all the products of the user with there product type, try to run it on your db to see it in action. then use foreach statement to fetch the results

Answer (score 1):

What I do to debug queries is to first start with the top query and then look at the results. Then I append one statement to it and look at the result again.

So for your case, you can start with the simple case of:

```
$this->db->select('users.*');
$this->db->from('users');
```

Look at the result and then add another statement:

```
$this->db->select('users.*');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->like('users.company_name',$string,'both');
```

Do this until you eventually form the whole query.

The point is somewhere along the way you will discover what statement is filtering your other expected results. This can also be done backwards.

Comment: I'm using a foreach loop and result(). I've just edited my question to highlight this